# Create a new vector with an existing vector

Tags: r

I am doing this practice problem that wants me to write a function that create a vector with an existing vector.
The example is if vector `a<-c(4, 0, 1, -2, 3)`, the output vector should be `4 5 -1 2 1`.
The rule is: if the existing vector `a` has `length = n`, the new vector`b` should be set as `length = n`, and each element is calculated in such way that `b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1]`. If any of these `a[i-1] a[i] a[i+1]` element does not exist, it should set to be equal to `0`.

```
z <- c(4, 0, 1, -2, 3)

solution <- function(n, a) {
  b <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (is.na(a[i - 1])) {
      a[i - 1] <- 0
    }
    else if (is.na(a[i])) {
      a[i] <- 0
    }
    else if (is.na(a[i + 1])) {
      a[i + 1] <- 0
    }
    b[i] <- a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
  }
  return(b)
}

solution(5, z)
```

With this I got this: `Error in if (is.na(a[i - 1])) { : argument is of length zero`

Then I change it to

```
solution <- function(n, a) {
  b <- c()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if (is.null(a[i - 1])) {
      a[i - 1] <- 0
    }
    else if (is.na(a[i])) {
      a[i] <- 0
    }
    else if (is.na(a[i + 1])) {
      a[i + 1] <- 0
    }
    b[i] <- a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
  }
  return(b)
}
```

But this time I got:

```
solution(5, z)
# [1] NA  5 -1  2  1
```

The first element of the new vector becomes `NA`.
What do I get wrong?

BTW I also tried to set `n = 12`

```
solution(12, z)
# [1] NA  5 -1  2  1  3  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

The result is okay after passing 5.

Comment: I added an answer replacing an old one (misread the Q), does this work as intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are working with an exercise, I will try to explain each step and arrive at a simple solution (that might not necessarily be the best). We see that everything is working except for the first element, so we know that the issue is at `i = 1`. What we can do is go through the loop for this value of `i` and see what happens.

```
i = 1
is.null(a[i - 1])
#> FALSE
```

Even though we think that this should be true (as there is no element before `i = 1`), the condition is still coming out to be `FALSE`. We can see what's happening directly:

```
a[i - 1]
#> numeric(0)
```

`numeric(0)` means an empty numeric vector (which is different from `NULL`). This happens when you subset a vector by index 0. Note that you can identify `numeric(0)` (and any empty vector) by checking whether its length is equal to 0:

```
length(a[i - 1]) == 0
#> TRUE
```

However, a different problem happens. Even after the condition is found to be `TRUE`, notice that setting the 0th element of a vector to a value doesn't do anything:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3)
x[0] = 10
x
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

And unfortunately there is another problem! You used `if` and `else if` statements, so whenever one of these branches is reached, the rest will not be executed. This means that if there is an issue with more than just one of `a[i - 1]`, `a[i]`, and `a[i + 1]`, only the first issue found will be fixed.

I want to steer us in a different direction that will resolve all of these problems.  First we need to address the issue with the start and ending of the vector. This can be done by just appending 0 to the beginning and end of the vector:

```
a = c(0, a, 0)
```

Next, we need to to set any `NA` within `a` to be 0:

```
a[is.na(a)] = 0
```

Now we are ready to solve the problem using a loop as you did, but this time it's very simple:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  b[i] = a[i] + a[i + 1] + a[i + 2]
}
```

The last thing - instead of having `n` be a parameter of the function, we can do better by just using `length(a)`. But the best is to simply use `seq_along(a)`, as I will show below. Putting it all together:

```
solution = function(a) {
  x = c(0, a, 0)
  x[is.na(x)] = 0
  b = c()
  for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    b[i] = x[i] + x[i + 1] + x[i + 2]
  }
  b
}
```

As you continue learning R you will see that there are many nice ways to solve the problem, such as the solutions given in the other answers.

Comment: This explained the problem very clear! I am very new to programming. Things like "seq_along(a)", I don't even know they exist. Do you have any recommended books/websites/tutorials that I can systematically learn R? I am an econometric student. Most of the time that I use R, I only use premade tools to solve the problem. Learning the programming actually costs me a lot of chaos...

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info has many resources. A challenging option I used is "Advanced R" (full book https://adv-r.hadley.nz/index.html) - since you say that you want to learn R systematically, this book may benefit you (chapters 1-11). If it's too dense, use it as a reference and read it as you become more familiar with R. "R for Data Science" (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html) is a great book to show you how to work with data in R (using the tidyverse). Learning R takes time and exposure. And people in this community are always happy to help :)

Comment: You can read more about `seq_along()` in Advanced R section 5.3.1: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/control-flow.html?q=loops#common-pitfalls. The summary is that it acts like `1:length(x)`, except it handles edge cases (like `x` being an empty vector) better.

Comment: I will bookmark these links. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

This applies along a vector that is used to index a

```
sapply(seq(length(a)), function(i) sum(a[(i-1):(i+1)], na.rm=TRUE))
```

If you want that as a function

```
solution <- function(x) { 
  sapply(seq(length(x)), function(i) sum(x[(i-1):(i+1)], 
na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: This looks simple and nice. But I don't even know the command "sapply()" exists... How can I improve?

Comment: `sapply()` belongs to the `apply` family of functions - it takes an object and a function, and applies the function to each element of the object. E.g. a vector of five values and the print function... `sapply(1:5, print)` or a custom function `sapply(1:5, function(i){i*i})`

Answer (score 0):

As this is a vector you can do it without any loop and do simply sum up the lag, the value and the lead. this gives you the vector with NA values for the first and last value which you convert to 0.

```
z <- c(4, 0, 1, -2, 3)

solution <- function(z) {
  z <- lag(z) + z + lead(z)
  z[is.na(z)] <- 0
  z
}

solution(z)

# [1]  0  5 -1  2  0
```

**Edit** as it was not clear how to interpret OP's *"If any of these a[i-1] a[i] a[i+1] element does not exist, it should set to be equal to 0."* the solution with the mentioned expected output.

```
solution <- function(z) {
  z <- c(0, z, 0)
  z <- lag(z) + z + lead(z)
  z[!is.na(z)]
}

solution(z)

# [1]  4  5 -1  2  1
```

Or even shorter as oneliner

```
solution <- function(z) {
  c(0, na.omit(lag(z))) + z + c(na.omit(lead(z)), 0)
}

solution(z)

# [1]  4  5 -1  2  1
```

**Benchmarks of all answers**

Aight, lets do some benchmarks and see why you want to prevent any loops or even apply functions when it is not 100% needed. Of course I increased the vector size for this.

```
set.seed(42)
z <- sample(-5:5, 100000L, replace = TRUE)

solution1 <- function(z) {
  z <- c(0, z, 0)
  z <- lag(z) + z + lead(z)
  z[!is.na(z)]
}

solution2 <- function(z) {
  c(0, na.omit(lag(z))) + z + c(na.omit(lead(z)), 0)
}

solution3 <- function(x) { 
  sapply(seq(length(x)), function(i) sum(x[(i-1):(i+1)], na.rm=TRUE))
}

solution4 <- function(a) {
  b <- vector('numeric', length(a))
  for (i in seq.int(a)) {
    A <- list(a[i - 1], a[i], a[i + 1])
    for (j in seq.int(A)) {
      if (length(A[[j]]) == 0 || is.na(A[[j]])) {
        A[[j]] <- 0
      }
    }
    b[i] <- A[[1]] + A[[2]] + A[[3]]
  }
  return(b)
}

solution5 = function(a) {
  a = c(0, a, 0)
  a[is.na(a)] = 0
  b = c()
  for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    b[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1]
  }
  b
}

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(
  "solution1" = {
    solution1(z)
  },
  "solution2" = {
    solution2(z)
  },
  "solution3" = {
    solution3(z)
  },
    "solution4" = {
    solution4(z)
  },
  "solution5" = {
    solution5(z)
  },
  replications = 50,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative")
)


       test replications elapsed relative
1 solution1           50    0.27     1.35
2 solution2           50    0.20     1.00
3 solution3           50   10.82    54.10
4 solution4           50   12.15    60.75
5 solution5           50    1.73     8.65
```

Comment: Does not matter too much, and getting a deja vu from yesterday's discussion, point is that on bigger data loops and especially for loops are going to be slow. Here the gain can be made preventing the loops as summing vectors sum each value of the vector. this is powerful and fast, so we only need to append the lag and the lead according to the OP's interpretation of the expected outcome.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and going deep on this. Now, I understand that unnecessary loops cause chaos that slow down the execution. But I don't know what could be the other way to simply solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is about the `numeric(0)` which instead of being `NULL` is actually a vector of length zero.

```
is.null(numeric(0))
# [1] FALSE

length(numeric(0)) == 0
# [1] TRUE
```

You could put the three `a[.]` in a `list` `A`, replace them if their length is zero or they are `NA`, and calculate with the list elements. Vector `b` may be initialized using `vector` with a specific length (since it's known) which is more efficient. I am not sure why `n` is needed at all, when we loop over the sequences along `a` using `seq_along()`.

```
solutionA <- function(a) {
  b <- vector('numeric', length(a))
  for (i in seq_along(a)) {
    A <- list(a[i - 1], a[i], a[i + 1])
    for (j in seq_along(A)) {
      if (length(A[[j]]) == 0 || is.na(A[[j]])) {
        A[[j]] <- 0
      }
    }
    b[i] <- A[[1]] + A[[2]] + A[[3]]
  }
  return(b)
}

solutionA(z)
# [1]  4  5 -1  2  1
```

For sake of speed we may use `vapply()`, which is similar to [*@rg255*'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70469903/6574038), except for the initialization of RAM of the type `"numeric"` with `0`.

```
solutionC <- function(x) { 
  vapply(seq_along(x), \(i) sum(x[(i - 1):(i + 1)], na.rm=TRUE), 0)
}

solutionC(z)
# [1]  4  5 -1  2  1
```

Here a **Benchmark**:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#     for 103.0531 110.3464 119.5067 115.9603 126.5834 167.9031   100  b 
#  sapply 107.2445 118.2517 127.2979 124.0168 131.2903 192.3599   100   c
#  vapply 102.2778 109.1570 114.6262 113.8659 119.3710 135.1884   100 a
```

*Code:*

```
z1 <- rep(z, 1e5)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark('for'=solution_jayFor(z1), 
                               sapply=solution_rg255(z1),
                               vapply=solution_jayVapply(z1), 
                               times=10L, control=list(warmup=10L))
```